# How to split an an atomic vector or a data column within a data frame in R

Tags: dataframe, vector, split

I'm trying to either split one data column within a data frame into multiple columns added onto the existing data frame, or split up the atomic vector I created in an effort to identify individual variables using conditionals.

I'm using a data set that was created in Brazil so it has already had many formatting issues I've already corrected. ex. commas instead of decimals, adjusting date/time formats, etc. The biggest problem I'm now having is the final column in the data frame with the rows containing between 1-6 results.

This is what I've gotten to thus far and am receiving this error:
Error in CF_IDs$IDs : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

```
CF_IDs <- NewSet1$IDs[ ((NewSet1$Behaviour == "DP" | NewSet1$Behaviour == "P") & NewSet1$Interaction == "S") ]
str_split_fixed[CF_IDs$IDs, ",", 6]
```

Right now my data frame looks like this:

```
Behaviour|Interaction|IDs
P        |S          |15L,33L,38L
D        |N          |43L,17L
D        |N          |9L,10L
```

I'm trying to split up the IDs column while also not creating an issue with NAs. I want to separate them individually in order to figure out each unique variable out of 52 instead of what is currently out of 403.

*Edit: Turning the last column into multiple rows would also work, but I have no idea how to do that. It would potentially look something like:

```
Behaviour|Interaction|IDs
P        |S          |15L
P        |S          |33L
P        |S          |38L
D        |N          |43L
D        |N          |17L
D        |N          |9L
D        |N          |10L
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it and wanted to post in case someone else stumbles upon this.

```
#Separate IDs column into individual rows with corresponding Behavior and Interaction variables
NewSet1_IDs <- separate_rows(NewSet1, IDs)
#Remove rows caused by blank space at the end of IDs in original data set
NewSet1_IDs <- NewSet1_IDs[!(NewSet1_IDs$IDs == ""),]
```

This gives the desired result.